# Calcular o produto dentro de um loop for

Tags: c, loop, for

Preciso calcular o produto de 3 números dentro de um loop for, mas o código que eu fiz está dando errado, multiplicando uma coisa bizarra que eu nem consegui entender, por exemplo, se inputar 1, 1, 1, ele retorna 16. Como calcular um produto dentro de um loop for em C?
Segue o código:

```
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");

    int num, soma, produto, menor, maior = 1;

    for(int n = 0; n < 3; n++){
        printf("Digite o número %i: ", n + 1);
        scanf("%i", &num);
        soma = soma + num;
        produto = produto * num;


    }
printf("Soma: %i\n", soma);
printf("Produto: %i", produto);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A variavel soma deve ser inicializada `soma = 0` e tambem a variavel `produto = 1`. Do contrario elas estarão recebendo lixo e os calculos ficam errados.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{

  int num, soma=0, produto=1, menor, maior = 1;

  for(int n = 0; n < 3; n++){
      printf("Digite o número %i: ", n + 1);
      scanf("%i", &num);
      soma = soma + num;
      produto = produto * num;
  }
  printf("Soma: %i\n", soma);
  printf("Produto: %i", produto);
  return 0;
 }
```